# Android draw multiple bitmaps next to each other

Tags: java, android

I need to customize an ImageView so that several images are displayed next to each other like This:
[IMG][IMG]

My original code looks like this:

```
    @Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

  super.onDraw(canvas);
  canvas.drawBitmap(img1, 10, 10, null);
  canvas.drawBitmap(img2, fourtyfive.getScaledWidth(canvas)+10, 10, null);

}
```

What I'm trying to do is place the first image, get it's scaled device-specific width then place the second image at an offset based on the width the first.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is happening with what you have?  What is the value returned by getScaledWidth()? And if you are scaling the bitmaps yourself, don't you already have the width that you scaled it to?

Comment: Looks like I figured this out...It was a stupid mistake. My code was working, but the view in the layout was not wide enough to display the second image.